# Finding exact word in a comma separated list in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a comma separated list in a node , I want to find the exact word using contains function it's not finding for perfect word, it's picking up a substring also.

my xml node will be looks like

```
<myapplication><NameValue name="DPEDA.PARAMETER10">REQADDINFO,REQADDINFOType2, ACCEPT,APPLETT</NameValue></myapplication>
```

when ever i give "APP" word it's returning as true with contains function. I want return true if i provide exact word only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude partial matches in XPath 1.0, you need to prepend and append the delimiter:

```
//myapplication[contains(
    concat(',', NameValue[@name='DPEDA.PARAMETER10'], ','),
    concat(',', $searchWord, ',')
)]
```

i.e. search for `',APP,'` in the string `',REQADDINFO,REQADDINFOType2, ACCEPT,APPLETT,'`.

---

In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) you can use `tokenize()`, for example like this:

```
//myapplication[$searchWord = tokenize(NameValue[@name='DPEDA.PARAMETER10'], ',')]
```